# Django order by across foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model that can be connected to one of two models. I have it set as such:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    foo_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

now both `Foo` and `Bar` have a field called `date_created` with a datetime. If I have the following queryset:

```
queryset = Example.objects.all()
```

**how can I have it order by `date_created` regardless of which model the foreign key is to?**

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `queryset = Example.objects.order_by('foo__date_created','bar__date_created')` work?

Comment: No because that will first order by `foo__date_created` and then by `bar__date_created` when they need to be ordered with the same priority

Comment: @RyanSaxe how can you possibly order on two fields and not prioritise one ?

Comment: But, according to what you said, an Example will only have one Foo _or_ one Bar. The priority will be equal.

Comment: @RobL that is true, I completely misunderstood my own logic and overcomplicated the situation. This should work. I will accept this answer once I test it out

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli and I do that because only one will ever exist, so there can't be an actual priority

Comment: @RobL columns are not nullable in the code, but let assume they are; I bet you are going to get some very "interesting" results when sorting on them :)

Comment: @RobL if you sort on nullable column keep in mind that you are going to have wrong sorting. eg. the records with foo not set will always be on top (or bottom depend on sort order) regardless the value of bar (which is the one you actually care about).

Comment: Well, in that case, you'll need a `CASE` statement in raw sql or some hairy `extra`s.

Comment: so there is no "easy" way to do this in Django?

Comment: Well, it'll have to be something like this: `queryset = Example.objects.extra(select={'o':'(case when foo__date_created IS NOT NULL then foo__date_created when bar__date_created IS NOT NULL then bar__date_created end)', order_by='o'}` But the `date_created` columns may have to include the through tables name.

Comment: I think I am just going to add a date created field and use a signal to make sure the date_created on my model is correct in corresponding to the relation